# RStudio 起動時にフリーズし、操作不能のまま動作が停止する

Tags: r

何度アンインストールをし、再インストールしても件名の症状が出て動作停止してしまいます。

あるRmdファイルを開いたまま終了`q()`してしまったため、起動時に自動的にそれを読み込む際にエラーが生じているのかと思い、削除したり戻したりや、.RDataを同様にしたりしてもうまくいきません。

つきましては、
１）動作停止を回避する手段（エラー内容は文末に記載）
　または、
２）起動時に`.r`や`.Rmd`ファイルを開かない状態でRStudioを起動する方法

などがございましたら、ご教示いただけますと幸いです。

なお、エラー内容は以下のようになっております。

```
Version=1
EventType=BEX
EventTime=131620094135754832
ReportType=2
Consent=1
UploadTime=131620094140308282
ReportStatus=268435456
ReportIdentifier=3774fad3-f547-4dea-8295-cef91391396e
IntegratorReportIdentifier=cb770f67-0d6b-4353-ac7d-d36deedeafdc
Wow64Host=34404
Wow64Guest=332
NsAppName=rstudio.exe
AppSessionGuid=00000ed8-0001-002c-4f26-a732c79bd301
TargetAppId=W:000600dad2dd7b56e9df48efd2ba48dcbd8d00000904!000022dabcb4dd50a4689f9554cbdf341b2c4bef8cb5!rstudio.exe
TargetAppVer=2018//01//22:21:50:15!8341a9!rstudio.exe
BootId=4294967295
ServiceSplit=3539031
TargetAsId=954
Response.BucketId=386018450e5ae44d361ef49e3e79e47c
Response.BucketTable=5
Response.LegacyBucketId=1593980278625920124
Response.type=4
Sig[0].Name=アプリケーション名
Sig[0].Value=rstudio.exe
Sig[1].Name=アプリケーションのバージョン
Sig[1].Value=1.1.419.0
Sig[2].Name=アプリケーションのタイムスタンプ
Sig[2].Value=5a665c97
Sig[3].Name=障害モジュールの名前
Sig[3].Value=ssleay32.dll
Sig[4].Name=障害モジュールのバージョン
Sig[4].Value=0.0.0.0
Sig[5].Name=障害モジュールのタイムスタンプ
Sig[5].Value=39ff11cd
Sig[6].Name=例外オフセット
Sig[6].Value=00021788
Sig[7].Name=例外コード
Sig[7].Value=c0000005
Sig[8].Name=例外データ
Sig[8].Value=00000008
DynamicSig[1].Name=OS バージョン
DynamicSig[1].Value=10.0.15063.2.0.0.256.48
DynamicSig[2].Name=ロケール ID
DynamicSig[2].Value=1041
DynamicSig[22].Name=追加情報 1
DynamicSig[22].Value=2beb
DynamicSig[23].Name=追加情報 2
DynamicSig[23].Value=2beba6fb4680d73a8c78ca7c24ccdb46
DynamicSig[24].Name=追加情報 3
DynamicSig[24].Value=4a5d
DynamicSig[25].Name=追加情報 4
DynamicSig[25].Value=4a5d40b982f101d80531f52cc36580c0
UI[2]=C:\Users\user\Documents\RStudio\bin\rstudio.exe
UI[3]=RStudio は動作を停止しました
UI[4]=問題の解決策をオンラインで確認できます。
UI[5]=オンラインで解決策を確認してプログラムを終了します
UI[6]=オンラインで解決策を後で確認してプログラムを終了します
UI[7]=プログラムを終了します
LoadedModule[0]=C:\Users\user\Documents\RStudio\bin\rstudio.exe
LoadedModule[1]=C:\windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
LoadedModule[2]=C:\windows\System32\KERNEL32.DLL
LoadedModule[3]=C:\windows\System32\KERNELBASE.dll
LoadedModule[4]=C:\windows\System32\ADVAPI32.dll
LoadedModule[5]=C:\windows\System32\msvcrt.dll
LoadedModule[6]=C:\windows\System32\sechost.dll
LoadedModule[7]=C:\Users\user\Documents\RStudio\bin\Qt5Core.dll
LoadedModule[8]=C:\windows\System32\RPCRT4.dll
LoadedModule[9]=C:\Users\user\Documents\RStudio\bin\Qt5Network.dll
LoadedModule[10]=C:\Users\user\Documents\RStudio\bin\Qt5Gui.dll
LoadedModule[11]=C:\windows\System32\ole32.dll
LoadedModule[12]=C:\windows\System32\SspiCli.dll
LoadedModule[13]=C:\windows\System32\CRYPT32.dll
LoadedModule[14]=C:\windows\System32\GDI32.dll
LoadedModule[15]=C:\windows\System32\combase.dll
LoadedModule[16]=C:\windows\System32\CRYPTBASE.dll
LoadedModule[17]=C:\windows\System32\ucrtbase.dll
LoadedModule[18]=C:\windows\System32\gdi32full.dll
LoadedModule[19]=C:\windows\System32\bcryptPrimitives.dll
LoadedModule[20]=C:\windows\System32\msvcp_win.dll
LoadedModule[21]=C:\windows\System32\MSASN1.dll
LoadedModule[22]=C:\windows\System32\USER32.dll
LoadedModule[23]=C:\windows\System32\OLEAUT32.dll
LoadedModule[24]=C:\windows\System32\WS2_32.dll
LoadedModule[25]=C:\windows\System32\win32u.dll
LoadedModule[26]=C:\windows\System32\SHELL32.dll
LoadedModule[27]=C:\windows\System32\cfgmgr32.dll
LoadedModule[28]=C:\windows\System32\shcore.dll
LoadedModule[29]=C:\Users\user\Documents\RStudio\bin\Qt5WebKit.dll
LoadedModule[30]=C:\Users\user\Documents\RStudio\bin\Qt5PrintSupport.dll
LoadedModule[31]=C:\windows\System32\windows.storage.dll
LoadedModule[32]=C:\windows\System32\SHLWAPI.dll
LoadedModule[33]=C:\windows\System32\COMDLG32.DLL
LoadedModule[34]=C:\windows\System32\kernel.appcore.dll
LoadedModule[35]=C:\windows\System32\powrprof.dll
LoadedModule[36]=C:\windows\System32\profapi.dll
LoadedModule[37]=C:\Users\user\Documents\RStudio\bin\libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll
LoadedModule[38]=C:\windows\SYSTEM32\MPR.DLL
LoadedModule[39]=C:\windows\SYSTEM32\DNSAPI.DLL
LoadedModule[40]=C:\Users\user\Documents\RStudio\bin\libwinpthread-1.dll
LoadedModule[41]=C:\Users\user\Documents\RStudio\bin\libstdc++-6.dll
LoadedModule[42]=C:\windows\System32\NSI.dll
LoadedModule[43]=C:\windows\SYSTEM32\OPENGL32.DLL
LoadedModule[44]=C:\Users\user\Documents\RStudio\bin\icuuc53.dll
LoadedModule[45]=C:\windows\SYSTEM32\VERSION.dll
LoadedModule[46]=C:\Users\user\Documents\RStudio\bin\Qt5Sql.dll
LoadedModule[47]=C:\windows\SYSTEM32\WINMM.DLL
LoadedModule[48]=C:\Users\user\Documents\RStudio\bin\Qt5Positioning.dll
LoadedModule[49]=C:\Users\user\Documents\RStudio\bin\Qt5Multimedia.dll
LoadedModule[50]=C:\Users\user\Documents\RStudio\bin\Qt5Sensors.dll
LoadedModule[51]=C:\Users\user\Documents\RStudio\bin\Qt5WebChannel.dll
LoadedModule[52]=C:\windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_5.82.15063.413_none_55bc94a37c2a2854\COMCTL32.dll
LoadedModule[53]=C:\windows\SYSTEM32\WINSPOOL.DRV
LoadedModule[54]=C:\windows\SYSTEM32\GLU32.dll
LoadedModule[55]=C:\windows\SYSTEM32\winmmbase.dll
LoadedModule[56]=C:\windows\SYSTEM32\bcrypt.dll
LoadedModule[57]=C:\Users\user\Documents\RStudio\bin\Qt5WebKitWidgets.dll
LoadedModule[58]=C:\Users\user\Documents\RStudio\bin\icuin53.dll
LoadedModule[59]=C:\Users\user\Documents\RStudio\bin\Qt5Widgets.dll
LoadedModule[60]=C:\Users\user\Documents\RStudio\bin\Qt5Quick.dll
LoadedModule[61]=C:\Users\user\Documents\RStudio\bin\Qt5Qml.dll
LoadedModule[62]=C:\Users\user\Documents\RStudio\bin\icudt53.dll
LoadedModule[63]=C:\Users\user\Documents\RStudio\bin\Qt5MultimediaWidgets.dll
LoadedModule[64]=C:\Users\user\Documents\RStudio\bin\Qt5OpenGL.dll
LoadedModule[65]=C:\windows\System32\IMM32.DLL
LoadedModule[66]=C:\windows\SYSTEM32\IPHLPAPI.DLL
LoadedModule[67]=C:\Users\user\Documents\RStudio\bin\plugins\platforms\qwindows.dll
LoadedModule[68]=C:\windows\system32\uxtheme.dll
LoadedModule[69]=C:\windows\system32\dwmapi.dll
LoadedModule[70]=C:\windows\System32\MSCTF.dll
LoadedModule[71]=C:\windows\System32\clbcatq.dll
LoadedModule[72]=C:\windows\system32\dataexchange.dll
LoadedModule[73]=C:\windows\system32\d3d11.dll
LoadedModule[74]=C:\windows\system32\dcomp.dll
LoadedModule[75]=C:\windows\system32\dxgi.dll
LoadedModule[76]=C:\windows\system32\twinapi.appcore.dll
LoadedModule[77]=C:\windows\system32\userenv.dll
LoadedModule[78]=C:\Users\user\Documents\RStudio\bin\plugins\imageformats\qgif.dll
LoadedModule[79]=C:\Users\user\Documents\RStudio\bin\plugins\imageformats\qico.dll
LoadedModule[80]=C:\Users\user\Documents\RStudio\bin\plugins\imageformats\qjpeg.dll
LoadedModule[81]=C:\Users\user\Documents\RStudio\bin\plugins\imageformats\qmng.dll
LoadedModule[82]=C:\Users\user\Documents\RStudio\bin\plugins\imageformats\qsvg.dll
LoadedModule[83]=C:\Users\user\Documents\RStudio\bin\Qt5Svg.dll
LoadedModule[84]=C:\Users\user\Documents\RStudio\bin\plugins\imageformats\qtga.dll
LoadedModule[85]=C:\Users\user\Documents\RStudio\bin\plugins\imageformats\qtiff.dll
LoadedModule[86]=C:\windows\SYSTEM32\CRYPTSP.dll
LoadedModule[87]=C:\windows\system32\rsaenh.dll
LoadedModule[88]=C:\windows\System32\TextInputFramework.dll
LoadedModule[89]=C:\windows\System32\CoreMessaging.dll
LoadedModule[90]=C:\windows\System32\CoreUIComponents.dll
LoadedModule[91]=C:\windows\SYSTEM32\usermgrcli.dll
LoadedModule[92]=C:\windows\SYSTEM32\ntmarta.dll
LoadedModule[93]=C:\windows\SYSTEM32\wintypes.dll
LoadedModule[94]=C:\Windows\System32\IME\IMEJP\imjptip.dll
LoadedModule[95]=C:\windows\SYSTEM32\iertutil.dll
LoadedModule[96]=C:\windows\SYSTEM32\PROPSYS.dll
LoadedModule[97]=C:\windows\SYSTEM32\OLEACC.dll
LoadedModule[98]=C:\Windows\System32\IME\IMEJP\imjpapi.dll
LoadedModule[99]=C:\windows\SYSTEM32\ncrypt.dll
LoadedModule[100]=C:\windows\SYSTEM32\NTASN1.dll
LoadedModule[101]=C:\Windows\System32\IME\shared\imjkapi.dll
LoadedModule[102]=C:\windows\SYSTEM32\policymanager.dll
LoadedModule[103]=C:\windows\SYSTEM32\msvcp110_win.dll
LoadedModule[104]=C:\Windows\System32\IME\IMEJP\imjppred.dll
LoadedModule[105]=C:\Windows\System32\IME\shared\imetip.dll
LoadedModule[106]=C:\windows\SYSTEM32\DUI70.dll
LoadedModule[107]=C:\Windows\System32\IME\shared\imecfm.dll
LoadedModule[108]=C:\windows\SYSTEM32\wer.dll
LoadedModule[109]=C:\Windows\System32\IME\SHARED\imesearchdll.dll
LoadedModule[110]=C:\windows\system32\ssleay32.dll
LoadedModule[111]=C:\windows\SYSTEM32\LIBEAY32.dll
LoadedModule[112]=C:\windows\SYSTEM32\WSOCK32.dll
LoadedModule[113]=C:\windows\system32\winhttp.dll
LoadedModule[114]=C:\windows\SYSTEM32\dhcpcsvc6.DLL
LoadedModule[115]=C:\windows\SYSTEM32\dhcpcsvc.DLL
LoadedModule[116]=C:\windows\system32\mswsock.dll
LoadedModule[117]=C:\Windows\System32\rasadhlp.dll
LoadedModule[118]=C:\windows\System32\fwpuclnt.dll
State[0].Key=Transport.DoneStage1
State[0].Value=1
FriendlyEventName=動作が停止しました
ConsentKey=BEX
AppName=RStudio
AppPath=C:\Users\user\Documents\RStudio\bin\rstudio.exe
NsPartner=windows
NsGroup=windows8
ApplicationIdentity=86F14E3EC45C2BB30DF490C55B7D5A76
MetadataHash=-537063398
```

宜しくお願い申し上げます。